# Double arrow syntax within Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In Javascript, what does the following syntax imply within a function? After passing in the props to the function, another arrow syntax is used further within the function. Is this used to de-structure the props further?

```
import React 'react';

const createDataList =
  ({
    dataOptions = {},
    settings,
    style,
    width,
  }) =>
  ({
    HeaderComponent,
    dataRows = [],
    states = [],
    dataFilterRows = [],
    onItemSelect,
    mappedEvents = {},
    onRefresh,
    onDateSelect,
    onEndReached,
    onScroll,
    refreshing,
    loading,
    endReached,
  }) => {
    // functionality implementation
  };
export default createDatasetList;
```

Comment: It's a function that returns a function

Comment: `function createDataList (generatorOptions) {return function (options) { /* ... */}}`